# image with more size is not occupying full space in product view page in magento

Tags: image, product-view

please visit this link :

http://www.kidsdial.com/ottoman.html is product 1

alse we can see the base image is not occupying full space as compare to follwing link

but you can see here, product 2 : http://www.kidsdial.com/htc-touch-diamond.html

here, base image is occupying full space.

product 1's image is having more height and width size but why the product 1's image is

not occupying full space in products view page

please help me to find some solution....

Comment: http://www.kidsdial.com/media/catalog/product//1/1/1192_resized_5.jpg this is your original image.then how you say not occupying fullspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image uploaded includes white space around it: http://www.kidsdial.com/media/catalog/product/1/1/1192_resized_5.jpg

Cropping out the white space should make it appear larger on the frontend after you upload the fixed image.
h image is not occupying full space in product detail page